# Does Erlang have a way to get the current continuation?

Tags: erlang, continuations

Does Erlang have a way to reify the current continuation? I'm thinking something like Scheme/Racket's `call-with-current-continuation` or `let/cc`.

I am aware that there are some issues surrounding continuations and concurrency. (I'm reading a paper on "subcontinuations" right now that is discussing some of these issues.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a feature supported in Erlang.

Comment: Thanks, first of all. Is this mentioned explicitly anywhere in the docs? Or is it simply not listed in the documentation?

Comment: Simply unlisted.